# Swapping two images on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to make two different images change when the user clicks a button. I got the first image to change, but now I don't know how to have the next image change at the same time...

It works like this: Both starts as blue. After mouse-click, the left image will display the following sequence (ballblue, ballred, ballred...) the right image on the same button click will display the following (ballred, ballblue, ballred...).

I got this to work, but now how do I make the second image change in a different order (starts out as ballblue.gif, then on button click to ballred.gif, then ballblue.gif, and finally ballred.gif?

Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head><title></title></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
imgsleft=Array("ballblue.gif","ballblue.gif","ballred.gif","ballred.gif");
var x=0;

function lampSwitch()
{
    document.getElementById("left").src=imgsleft[++x];    
    if (x==3) {
        x=-1;
    }
}
if (!imgs[x+1]) {
    x=-1;
}
</script>
<body>
    <img src="ballblue.gif" id="left" alt="alttext" height="12" width="12"/>
    <img src="ballblue.gif" id="right" alt="alttext" height="12" width="12"/>
    <form action="#">
        <p><input type="button" value="Switch" onclick="lampSwitch()" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just want to clarify if I got your idea right. Upon loading, ballblue (on left) and ballred (on right) will be displayed. Then upon clicking, they will switch color alternatively?

Comment: Upon loading ballblue (on left) and again ballbue (on right) will be displayed.. on button click, left image will stay blue, on next click it will turn red, and finally on next click it will stay red.. The right image, however is different. It starts out blue, then on click it goes to ballred, then ballblue, then again to ball red

Comment: Both images will change at the same time (when the button is clicked)

Comment: I edited my answer, they now alternately switch colors.

Comment: I want them to have the same image starting out, then change pattern as the button is clicked..

Comment: Yes, my code works now as you wanted, which both starts blue then change pattern after click. I just copied your html body without modification since both image have the same src, which initially start both in blue. I will now edit my answer to include my whole html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code for alternating color:**

```
<html>
<head><title>Lamp Switch</title></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
imgsleft=Array("ballblue.gif","ballred.gif");
var x=0;

function lampSwitch(){
    if(++x % 2){
        document.getElementById("left").src=imgsleft[0];
        document.getElementById("right").src=imgsleft[1];
    }else{
        document.getElementById("left").src=imgsleft[1];
        document.getElementById("right").src=imgsleft[0];   
    }
} 
</script>
<body>
<img src="ballblue.gif" id="left" alt="alttext" height="12" width="12"/>
<img src="ballblue.gif" id="right" alt="alttext" height="12" width="12"/>
<form action="#">
<p><input type="button" value="Switch" onclick="lampSwitch()" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code for your specified pattern:**

Both starts as blue.

Below is the pattern after button click

left: blue red red...blue red red...blue red red (and repeats the same pattern)

right: blue red blue red blue red blue .....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
imgsleft = Array("ballblue.gif","ballred.gif");
pattern = Array("ballblue.gif","ballred.gif","ballred.gif");
var x=0;
var y=0;
function lampSwitch(){
    if(++x % 2){
        document.getElementById("right").src=imgsleft[1];
    }else{
        document.getElementById("right").src=imgsleft[0];   
    }

    y++;
    if(y == 3){
       y = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("left").src=pattern[y];
} 
</script>
```

Comment: That only changes the left image, not the right... The left image will display the following on button click (ballblue, ballred, and ballred) the right image on the same button click will display the following (ballred, ballblue, ballred) [both images start out ballblue]

Comment: It is working for me now... upon loading, both are blue. Then switching color alternatively upon click. I didn't modify the html body, just the function definition.

Comment: OK. I'll give it a try.. Thanks for being patient

Comment: Hmm. by the way I they aren't supposed to be switching color, just displaying two different images at the same time. The left displays blue, red, red// and the right image displays red, blue red

Comment: So they have different pattern. Maybe you'll need two separate arrays then that contains the pattern.

Comment: Yep. But that is where I get confused. I don't know javaScript so I don't know how to add two separate arrays to do what I want it to do

Comment: I hope my latest modification is what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow! Now if I could just understand it! That is what I wanted. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
var currentIndex = 0;
var imgsleft = new Array("ballblue.gif","ballred.gif");

function lampSwitch()
 {
      document.getElementById("left").src=imgsleft[currentIndex%2];
      currentIndex++; 
 }
```

:p

Comment: Hmm, the code works great for the right image, but the left image does not change..

Comment: @TheCount Goodness sakes, read the code, understand the code, make it your own. This is not a spoon-feeding site designed to do your work for you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not used to JavaScript, and I guess it's hard to explain what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rocket99.com/techref/javascript8668.html this page contains Image Viewer with Prev and Next Buttons , I think this will help you.

Comment: Thanks but that link only shows me how to go through one image at a time. I was already able to figure this out. What I am looking for is JavaScript that will go change two separate images to two new images on a button click